# Recursive Query CTE Father - Son - Grandson error

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have a table that has an ID and IDFATHER of some projects, these projects can receive N sons, so, the structure is like

| ID | IDFATHER | REV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |

I need to, iniciating in ID 5 go to ID 1, so I did a CTE Query:

```
WITH lb (ID, IDFATHER) AS (
    SELECT ID, IDFATHER
    FROM PROJECTS
    WHERE ID = 5

    UNION ALL

    SELECT I.ID, I.IDFATHER
    FROM PROJECTS I
    JOIN lb LBI ON I.ID = LBI.IDFATHER
    --WHERE I.ID = LBI.IDFATHER -- Recursive Subquery 
)
SELECT *
FROM lb
WHERE LB.ID = LB.IDFATHER
```

When this code runs it gives me:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted
> before statement completion.

So basically I handle it by just adding:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM LB WHERE  LB.ID = LB.IDFATHER
```

But I really want to know were is my error. Can anyone give me a hand on these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion didn't stop because your top row refers to itself endlessly.

If the top row has a null parent, that would have stopped the recursion.

Another approach is to use that case `id = parentid` as the termination logic.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=43b827cd6010ad9dc5f586c96091b614)

```
WITH  LB (ID, IDFATHER, idstart) AS (
    SELECT ID,  IDFATHER, id
      FROM PROJECTS WHERE ID = 5
     UNION ALL 
    SELECT  I.ID,  I.IDFATHER, lbi.idstart
      FROM PROJECTS I 
      JOIN LB LBI
        ON  I.ID = lbi.IDFATHER 
       AND lbi.id <> lbi.idfather
      )

SELECT id AS idtop, idstart
  FROM LB
 WHERE LB.ID = LB.IDFATHER
;
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Tks a lot, a little mistake here :)

Answer (score 1):

The *first* row points to itself so the recursion never stops. You need to add this condition inside the recursive cte:

```
WHERE LBI.ID <> LBI.IDFATHER
```

I would rather set IDFather of the first row to NULL.

Comment: This is an ERP so I canté change this. But it was it! Tks a lot.